# Empty array when using this.props.data

Tags: reactjs

I used componentDidMount to execute fetch api to get data in REACT. And I assigned data to next component with props, using render, and the page did render. The data appeared too.

But above the component of the render, when using this.props.data the array was empty. Not sure why.

I've tried these ways but dont work:
1. async fetch 
2. this setState updater

Comment: i can not see your code

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 0):

Store the data you fetched in the component state and pass the this.state.data to the component you want to render the data as a prop.

PS: If you give us your code we can give you further help